# Bootstrap 3 an fix the border radius for an input with three input groups

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

Consider below html code, which uses bootstrap 3 input group to create an input three input groups.

```
<h1>border radius</h1>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input value="false" type="radio"/>
            </span>

             <div class="input-group"> 
                <span class="input-group-addon">*</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"/> 
                <span class="input-group-addon">?</span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The default bootstrap style puts border radius for all input groups, which is not good for the middle input groups (I mean the tiny left radius around `*` ).

To remove this radius, I try to set the border radius for all input groups to zero except the last one.

```
 div.input-group > div.input-group > span.input-group-addon:not:last-child{
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

But it did not work !

Please let me know what is wrong with this selector, and if I can do it easier !
fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mtamx8bs/

Comment: I realise you've already selected an answer and BoltClock's JSFiddle does achieve what you were asking for. But just out of curiosity, is there any particular reason you're trying to nest `input-group`s..? I think you might find something like this easier to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/mtamx8bs/3/

Comment: @ZaLiTHkA interesting, please send it as another answer, it is much better as it does not need no css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:not()` is a functional pseudo-class so [it needs parentheses around its argument](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/mtamx8bs/1):

```
div.input-group > div.input-group > span.input-group-addon:not(:last-child)
```

And on that note I removed the `!important` as it's no longer needed now that I've fixed the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way that Bootstrap applies the rounded border styling to the `.input-group-addon` class, only the first and last "addon" within an `.input-group` will end up with rounded corners.

Based on this, I'd suggest you consider wrapping all your required elements in a single input group, rather than trying to nest one inside the other.

For example:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><input value="false" type="radio"/></span>
    <span class="input-group-addon">*</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" /> 
    <span class="input-group-addon">?</span>
</div>
```

I updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtamx8bs/3/) with these changes if you want to play with it. (*Edit: or check [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/mtamx8bs/4/) for a slightly more verbose version, showing how much cleaner the code looks with multiple groups*)

As an extra note: there are some cases where you may end up nesting *different types* of "group" classes from Bootstrap, but you'll probably need to play with them to work out which combinations will achieve exactly what you want.

[This page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-segmented) in the docs shows an example of two button elements (normal button and a drop-down button) inside an `.input-group-btn` class, which is nested inside an `.input-group`.